# What am I missing to upgrade asp.net mvc .net core 2.2.0 apps to .net core 2.2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the latest version of visual studio, the sdk and runtimes for x64 and x86 version 2.2.1, but my asp.net mvc .net core applications will only recognize being 2.2.0.  I can install 2.2.1 into .net core libraries.

What do I need to change to allow my web projects to be 2.2.1 instead of 2.2.0?

(It can't be done through nuget, it provides the statement: Implicitly refrenced by an SDK. To update the package, update the SDK to which it belongs

Since the project is referencing a library with 2.2.1, I see the error: Error   NU1605  Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.AspNetCore.App from 2.2.1 to 2.2.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Microsoft documentation packages `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` and `Microsoft.NETCore.App` have special versioning semantics which is handled outside of NuGet.

Also note that specifying a version number on `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` package does not guarantee that desired version will be chosen. In general, you should not explicitly specify `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` version unless you have a good reason to do so (applies to .NET Core 2.1 and later).

You can read more about that here: [Microsoft.AspNetCore.App metapackage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/metapackage-app?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

If you want to target specific SDK used in your project or solution, add global.json file to project folder (if you want to target only that specific project) or solution folder if you want to target all projects in the solution.

global.json example:

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "2.2.103"
  }
}
```

Comment: I see, so it looks like it's running .net core 2.2.103 during startup, but the nuget package manager is showing that the project has 2.2.0 installed and won't let me install 2.2.103 (which I understand why it doesn't let me update it through there), but why doesn't it show as 2.2.103 there?  I added the global.json as you suggested but it still shows 2.2.0 in nuget.  I hear what you're saying, that you shouldn't specify, but what's telling it 2.2.0 vs 2.2.103 (I only have the 2.2.103 installed on my system to help it know which one I'm using)

Comment: In Package Manager Console run `Install-Package Microsoft.NETCore.App -Version 2.2.1`. You will get a warning though. I don't know why NuGet does not pick the latest version on its own. Might be a bug.

Comment: Thanks, says it ran successfully. I am seeing everything load from c:..\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.2.1, but nuget still shows 2.2.0, which is what it shows under the SDK dependencies.  I re-read the link you sent and I think it says that it always shows major.min.0, so maybe it's just a display issue.  I removed the explicit version from the dependency project's reference to the NetCore.App so it doesn't throw the downgrade error which was blocking build/run before. I think it's working as expected, but unclear based on what nuget is saying which might be the bug you're speaking of.